create-next-app error, while running the development server after all files generated by yarn or npm
This is the error that's looks like on the dev server

And this is the terminal error

Please suggest me possible fixes, why this occurred. i found a fix but this is not a correct way to edit these things...
Steps:

rename the file "postcss.config.mjs" to "postcss.config.js"

delete all the code of postcss.config.js and paste the below code..
   module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    };


install the 'autoprefixer' library

Restart the dev server


